# Importing functions of same name will overwrite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import, python-import

I want to import 2 functions from 2 different files, where the files have different names but the functions will have the same name. I want to execute the first function and then import the next one and execute that.

For example:

```
from file1 import func

func()

from file2 import func

func()
```

My question is whether at the 2nd call of func, will the function will be replaced by the one from file2? Or will it still use the one imported from file1?

Is it safe to overwrite it like this, or it's better if the function is named differently?

Comment: You can do: `from file1 import func as func1` and `from file2 import func as func2` to avoid collisions

Comment: What you have will work as you describe. But better for future readers of your code might just be: `import file1, file2; file1.func(); file2.func()`

Comment: No, it's not safe. It will just add to confusion and incorrect codes. Avoid it at all cost.

Comment: It would very simple to test this. Just create two functions that print something. Then create some code like this and see which messages are printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `from foo import func` and then later in the same module 
`from bar import func`, then you have simply defined `func` twice. But it can only point to one value, and that will be the most recent one. The first import might just as well never have had existed once you've
done the second one.

To avoid this you can do imports by assigning a different name on import:

`from foo import func as funcFoo`

Or you can just import only the module and then use:

`foo.func` and `bar.func`

Comment: Imports can have side effects, so while `func` would no longer refer to `file1.func`, there may be other observable affects from having imported `file1` in the first place.